# Map tile creation

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles, mapbox-studio

I am experienced in Leaflet and used Mapbox. But I think the time has come to have to bake our own tiles as the data has got so large.

Basically we need to show building level data around the world but with 100 variations. So you can select a variation and the buildings will colour accordingly, additionally we will need intractivity so when you hover or click on the map the application will provide information about the building.

I have looked around for quite a bit played with TileMill but found it hard to use and not look as compelling as Mapbox maps.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best stack / software to use for this?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/?

Comment: Thanks, but Im looking more for a solution to create the tiles, I think serving the tiles the easier part.